# Flutter: Send JSON body with dio package get request

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dio

[image: this API is working normal in postman]
however in flutter app its returning this

{"success": true,
"rslt": []}

where "rslt" is empty.

here's my code

```
dynamic getData(dynamic token) {
dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = '$token';
return await dio.get<dynamic>('https://address',
    queryParameters: <String,dynamic>{'cn': 'iPhone_11', 'qt': '20', 'ct': 'Delhi'});
}
```

What am I doing wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1):

In postman, you have added body to `GET` request. Normally `GET` request should not have body. But there is no body in your request in `Flutter`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using GET request instead of using a POST request?

Comment: If you want to add body, you should send POST request. You can send query parameters to server in GET request.

Comment: Thanks @utarid! I just had to change req.body.cn to req.query.cn and so on in my node.js code.

Comment: congratulations @samsonmarandi, please mark as correct answer if I was able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Change dio.get to dio.request:

```
  dio.request<dynamic>(
     'https://address',
     queryParameters: <String,dynamic>{
     'cn': 'iPhone_11', 'qt': '20', 'ct': 'Delhi'},
     options: Options(method: "GET"));
    }
```